# Python Regex to look for ALL special characters in a keyboard

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

I want to iterate through a dataframe (cell by cell) and check if it contains ANY special character in it. I'm unable to look for special characters like - period, square brackets, etc

```
#reading csv file into a df
df = pd.read_csv(data, sep=',', header='infer',encoding='latin1')

#empty lists
list1=[]
list2=[]

#regular expression for all special characters
regex = re.compile('[@_!#$%^&*()<>;,.?/\|}{~:]')

#iterating through all columns of the df
for col in df.columns:
#getting number of rows in the df
    countx=len(df)
    county=0
    for i in df[col]:
        if type(i)==str:

#if no special characters are found in the cell, subtracting 1 from countx
            if(regex.search(str(i)) == None):
                countx=countx-1

#if special characters are found in the value, adding 1 to county
            else: 
                county=county+1
                list2.append(i)
    if countx != 0 and county>0:
        list1.append(col)
```

Now, when I'm printing 'list1', I'm not getting columns that have certain special characters like - periods(.), square bracket([), etc.

Can someone help me with regex to look for ALL special characters present in a keyboard? Thanks!

Comment: The regex to match any special char is well known, it is `[^\w\s]|_`.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response. It solved my problem :)